# Make a swipe transition in a SurfaceListBox in PixelSense / WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, swipe, pixelsense

I have a `SurfaceListBox` that uses the `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`, so the transition does not look like a continuous drag, but it is immediate, you can see how it works here:  http://youtu.be/zyWmiN8GtpI.
There are two problems here: the transition is immediate; when I get to the end and swipe right (to get the item on the left) it sends me back to the first item.
Now I want to add a swipe effect transition to this, like you see on most smartphones and you can see here: http://youtu.be/O9xGHRL0Zn4 that works fine both ways.

I'm using a `SurfaceListBox`, but this can be made other ways, simply using WPF.
I looked around and I found some stuff in WPF, but all over-complicated for my purpose.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

*A sample project with the SurfaceListBox can be downloaded here: http://sdrv.ms/TJd3oy

Comment: Why do you have CanContentScroll turned on?  That answer will influence how to solve this

Comment: @RobertLevy Because that is closer to what I want to achieve, but if it is troubling you, you can just make it false.

Comment: this is unfortunately a non-trivial task but here is a blog series that will steer you in the right direction: http://surfacedeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/01/isurfacescrollinfo-and-you-epilogue.html